# git remote add command : How to edit remote tag in the .git/config file?

Tags: android, git, github, qualcomm

I'm currently working on gerrit setup to configure CAF repo to local server.
I have come across one problem.
The problem is whatever latest version of android I have download from CAF repo, it contains the following tag in .git/config file for remote.

```
[remote "caf"]
url = https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.18.git
review = codeaurora.org
projectname = kernel/msm-3.18
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/caf/*
```

Now I want to use this repo with local gerrit server therefore I need to use  [remote "origin"] as remote instead of [remote "caf"] and for that, I have supplied

```
git remote add origin ssh://XYZ@IP:PORT/qualcomm_625/kernel/msm-3.18.git
```

after that in the above config file new content are append like follow,

```
[remote "origin"]
url = ssh://XYZ@IP:PORT/qualcomm_625/kernel/msm-3.18.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

how can I add two missing "projectname" "review" lines using git remote add command?

Comment: Why not renaming the remote from `caf` to `origin` and maintain the remote extra properties?

Comment: if some one want to use caf remote then it creates a problem so multiple remotes like caf and origin will be a better idea in config file. that is what I think as of now.

Comment: More than one user will use the same computer?

Comment: As of now, user is one but other team members also could use. why two remote? let me explain if today I worked with my local repo which we have set up at that time remote "origin" will be used but for example if tomorrow I would like to push my changes to CAF then remote "caf" will be used. I just don't what to touch that CAF related things because it is what default is when I was sync repo. The additional remote info I would like to append only. That is my requirement is.

Comment: So, both `caf` and `origin` won't have the same url? Am i right? Extra properties like `review` and `projectname` are not standard properties for the remote definition on `git` so why you want those properties? You could also edit the file with a text editor and copy/paste the remote called `caf` and change its name (to the copy) to `origin`.

Comment: 1) both have different url. 2) regarding that extra property i'm not sure that it can be dynamically generate using any git command  or not(like using git remote add I can add remote tag called origin in config file) that why I have raise this question. 3) there are total 588 git repo in latest oreo source code. For that two extra property if somebody know about any specific git cmd that it is useful for me and i can directly call that cmd from script otherwise i need to edit file using sed and awk which is quite boring job to put that two property.

Comment: What's the point of those properties? `git remote add` does not have any extra parameters to add such data.

Comment: that is specific to Gerrit review I guess. ohh if such extra param I not supported using git remote add then the only way is to use stream editing. thanks.

Comment: Finally got it. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the custom values using `git config`.

1. Add your new origin: `git remote add origin path/to/repo.git`
2. Add the custom configuration using: `git config remote.origin.review review-data`

So in your case, to apply the same extra configuration as the example:

```
[remote "caf"]
url = https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.18.git
review = codeaurora.org
projectname = kernel/msm-3.18
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/caf/*
```

You can run the following commands:

1. `git remote add origin ssh://XYZ@IP:PORT/qualcomm_625/kernel/msm-3.18.git`
2. `git config remote.origin.review codeaurora.org`
3. `git config remote.origin.projectname kernel/msm-3.18`

You will get the new extra remote:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = ssh://XYZ@IP:PORT/qualcomm_625/kernel/msm-3.18.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
review = codeaurora.org
projectname = kernel/msm-3.18
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks... That what I really want.